# Use combinatorial arguments to prove the following binomial identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-explanation, combinatorial-proofs

Can anyone help prove this binomial identities by using the combinatorial arguments, I have no clue to get start. Thanks.
$$\binom{2n+1}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{k}$$

Comment: Have you tried for induction?

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you get stuck? Don't forget about providing this information in your question.

Comment: Perhaps start by considering/trying various classical combinatorial interpretations: choosing people from a group, rearranging letters, etc. Then, if you're still stuck, edit your question to let us know what you've tried.

Answer (score 4):

> The number of lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n+1,n)$ consisting of $(1,0)$-steps and $(0,1)$-steps is $$\binom{2n+1}{n}=\binom{2n+1}{n+1}$$ since we have to choose precisely $n+1$ $(1,0)$-steps out of $2n+1$ steps.

[image]

Each of these paths crosses the vertical line $x=n$ at a specific height $k$ with $0\leq k\leq n$.  There are $$\binom{n+k}{k}$$ paths crossing the vertical line $x=n$ at height $k$. Since this holds for each $0\leq k\leq n$

> we conclude
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{k}=\binom{2n+1}{n}}
> \end{align*}

Comment: is there a summation for RHS ?

Comment: @Student: Some more details added.

Comment: A nice argument.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Thanks for the credit.

Comment: Neat, i like it.

Comment: Hey Markus. May I ask where you get your diagrams?

Comment: @N.Shales: Checkout the latest version from GeoGebra and have fun. :-)

Comment: Will do!! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can write your formula like: $\binom{2n+1}{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{n} $
 Let $A$ be set , $\left| A \right|=2n+1$,and we can interpret left side like all subsets $B \subset A$, $\left| B \right|=n+1$. 
We can easily note that in every $B$ greatest element is at least $n+1$.Now family of all subsets $B$ we can divide into n+1 parts.
**first part**: all $B$ subsets in which $n+1$ is greatest element
**second part**:all $B$ subsets in which $n+2$ is greatest element.
....
**(n+1)-th part**:all $B$ subsets in which $2n+1$ is greatest element
Note that all parts are disjoint.
$\rightarrow$Cardinal number of first part is $\binom{n}{n}$ because we can only use elements smaller than $n+1$
$\rightarrow$Cardinal number of second part is $\binom{n+1}{n}$ because we can only use elements smaller than $n+2$
...
$\rightarrow$Cardinal number of (n+1)-th part is $\binom{2n}{n}$ because we can only use elements smaller than $2n+1$
Thus,right side is $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{n}$
We conclude:
 $$ \binom{2n+1}{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{n} $$