# Sum of Diagonal in Pascals triangle with power of 2

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that
$$\sum_{i=0}^n {{n+i}\choose {i}}  2^{-(n+i)} = 1 $$
I tried a direct approach and proof by induction, but the dependence of the exponent on $i$ throws me off every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is convenient  to use the *coefficient of* operator  $[z^n]$ to  denote the coefficient of  $z^n$  in  a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^n}&\color{blue}{\binom{n+i}{i}2^{-(i+n)}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^n[z^i](1+z)^{n+i}\frac{1}{2^i}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^n}[z^0](1+z)^n\sum_{i=0}^n\left(\frac{1+z}{2z}\right)^i\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^n}[z^0](1+z)^n\frac{\left(\frac{1+z}{2z}\right)^{n+1}-1}{\frac{1+z}{2z}-1}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}[z^{-1}]\frac{(1+z)^n}{1-z}\left[\left(\frac{1+z}{2z}\right)^{n+1}-1\right]\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}[z^n]\frac{(1+z)^{2n+1}}{1-z}\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{j}\tag{6}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot2^{2n+1}\\
> &\color{blue}{=1}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (3) we apply the *[finite geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*.
- In (4) we simplify the denominator and apply again the rule from (2).
- In (5) we observe that only the first term $\left(\frac{1+z}{2z}\right)^{n+1}$ gives a non-zero contribution to the coefficient of $[z^{-1}]$. We also do some more simplifications and apply again the rule from (2).
- In (6) we expand the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+z^2+\cdots$ and select the coefficient of $z^j$ with $0\leq j\leq n$.

Comment: your *coefficient of* approach hit again !

Comment: @GCab: Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

A nice way to visualise this problem is in terms of monotonic North/East (NE) [lattice paths](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_path).

If the probability of a North step is $1/2$ and of and East step is $1/2$ then, starting at $O(0,0)$ the probability that a path which leaves the box takes the leg between lattice points $(i,n)$ and $(i,n+1)$ is

$$\binom{n+i}{i}2^{-(n+i+1)}$$

This is also the probability a NE lattice path passes between $(n,i)$ and $(n+1,i)$.

The probability that a lattice path leaves the box defined by boundaries

$$\{y=-1/2,\, y=n+1/2,\, x=-1/2,\, x=n+1/2\}\tag{1}$$

is therefore the sum of probabilities that it leaves through boundary $y=n+1/2$ and boundary $x=n+1/2$. These are each:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n+i}{i}2^{-(n+i+1)}$$

and since *every* such NE lattice path must leave the box as defined by $(1)$ the sum of these two probabilities is $1$:

$$2\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n+i}{i}2^{-(n+i+1)}=1$$

or

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n+i}{i}2^{-(n+i)}=1$$

as required.

Comment: Nice approach. (+1)

Comment: Thanks Markus! I did it with your method using pen and paper (just to see if I could) but then saw you had already answered (+1 btw). So, for variation, I posted my other approach. I was pleased that you posted, though, because you confirmed for me that I had used your method correctly. Thanks again! :D

Comment: You're welcome, and I appreciate your lattice path approach. Sometimes I also like to *[do so](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2629896/use-combinatorial-arguments-to-prove-the-following-binomial-identities/2629964#2629964)*. :-)